# Debian SecureBoot with shim on MSI difficulty

Tags: uefi, secure-boot

I'm having a difficult time getting Debian 12 to boot UEFI with secureboot.

This is on an MSI Meg Z490 Unify motherboard. GPU is an AMD WX3200.
Secure Boot is enabled with standard mode and default keys are loaded. Testing was done with the GPU disconnected and using onboard graphics from an 10th gen i3

I originally installed debian with secureboot on, but after successful installation and rebooting it showed the bios screen then just blank. I assume this is the motherboard refusing to execute a bootloader because it is not signed? So I am not sure why a default debian installation (that is supposed to support secureboot) just didn't work on a clean installation. I disabled secureboot and booted into the system fine. `efibootmgr -v` shows it is using `shimx64.efi` and the shim-signed packages are installed.

I then attempted to reenable secureboot and add the `shimx64.efi` to the UEFI allowed signatures, which then got me to GRUB screen and when it tried to load the kernel, I got a `shim_lock protocol not found`. Which is also strange because the shim-signed package **is installed** and `efibootmgr -v` had `shimx64.efi` shown.

I then attempted several different combinations of the settings, default keys with standard mode, default keys with custom mode, with and without adding the signature from `shimx64.efi`, adding `shimx64.efi` and `grubx64.efi` signatures, deleting the blacklist signatures.

But on to my question, the MSI bios secureboot section has a whole key section in custom mode that allows adding your own platform key, allowed signatures, ect.

Why couldn't I just upload Debians UEFI signing CA cert to the allowed signatures and/or platform key and just boot GRUB directly?

And I did attempt this by loading the Debian CA into the allowed signatures. The key adds successfully to the variable and it says saved to nvram but after booting GRUB (this is supposedly after shim is removed from the system, verified with `efibootmgr -v`) its the same error with `shim_lock procotol not found`.

Does this mean that the SecureBoot UEFI actually loaded a bootloader that was not signed by Microsoft? After removing shim-signed packages, do I have to do anything to the kernel image (system boots fine with no shim and secureboot off)?

I realize it doesn't work, but why not? Why even have the ability to add keys to secureboot if it won't use them to verify the bootloader?

And sort of a side question, does anyone have any advice for getting shim to work with this MSI motherboard?

New Discovery:

After some more tinkering, it turns out removing all keys from secureboot section and only adding in Debians key to both the platform key and key exchange keys (not sure which one, both added at the same time) results in an infinite power loop where the PC doesn't even get to the BIOS screen (have to cmos reset to get control).

Comment: `It appears MSI has blacklisted the SecureBoot shim for Ubuntu and Debian variants of Linux ` https://linustechtips.com/topic/1385951-msi-b550-a-pro-secureboot-shim-for-debianubuntu-variants-blacklisted/ A solution I'm going to test  and is testable is to remove `Debian secure boot signer` key from blacklist in BIOS settings under secure boot section!